# Integrability Proof in Ross's Real Analysis Text

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

In Ross's Real Analysis text, he proves that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable over $[a,b]$, then $(f+g)$ is also integrable over $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b (f+g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$.

I understand everything until the last step of the proof. Ross strings together some inequalities to conclude: 
$$\int_a^b (f + g) < \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g + \epsilon$$
and
$$\int_a^b (f+g) > \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g - \epsilon$$
Thus, 
$$\int_a^b f + \int_a^b g - \epsilon < \int_a^b (f+g) < \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g + \epsilon$$
He then concludes from this
$$\int_a^b (f + g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$$
I don't understand how this conclusion follows. He makes several similar arguments, but various manipulations, such as adding $\epsilon$ to every term in the equality, doesn't quite get me there, and the strict inequalities doesn't seem to allow an argument of the kind $x \leq a \wedge x \geq a \implies x = a$.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

It is because 
\begin{align*}
-\epsilon<\int(f+g)-\left(\int f+\int g\right)<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left|\int(f+g)-\left(\int f+\int g\right)\right|<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
and you have probably known that $|a|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ implies that $|a|=0$, and hence $a=0$.

Comment: Excellent! This makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for this.